# Excel: Check if value occurs on one of several sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to check if the value "x" occurs in the cell A1 on one of many sheets.

Unfortunately, the match formula does not work if I reference to multiple sheets.

```
=MATCH("x";Sheet1:Sheet2!A1;0)
```

It would be great if you could help me out on this.

Best,

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Let's say you want to search in the cell A1 of 3 different worksheets the value X, maybe something like `=FIND("x";Hoja2!A1&Hoja3!A1&Hoja4!A1;1)`. What i did is just concatenate the values of each A1 of each worksheet in a single string, and then find if the character string X appears.

Comment: Are you using Excel 2016 Office 365 Edition?

Comment: @tigeravatar I would like the formula to return TRUE or FALSE

Answer (score 0):

IF YOU HAVE EXCEL 2016 OFFICE 365, you can use the following formula to return TRUE or FALSE if "x" appears in A1 through multiple sheets:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(FIND("x",CONCAT(Sheet1:Sheet2!A1))))
```

This won't work on other versions because the CONCAT function isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

Change < number of sheets > to the number of sheets you have:

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Sheet"&ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&< number of sheets >))&"'!A1"),"x"))`

This requires that your sheets are named "Sheet1", "Sheet2", etc.